# Replace several distinct strings in dataset (column) with integer values

Tags: excel, search, replace, automation, dataset

Dataset example:

```
ABC 
DEF
GHI
JKL
ABC
GHI
JKL
JKL
ABC
```

I have one column in my dataset that has three character strings in every cell, similar to the example above. I want to replace every unique occurence of a string with an incremented integer (first unique string = 1, second unique string = 2 etc.).

There are approx. 300 unique three letter combinations in that column.

So basically:
Go through column until first unique three letter combination and replace it with "1".
-> Go through the rest of the column and replace every same three letter combination with "1".

Go through column until second unique three letter combination and replace it with "2".
-> Go through the rest of the column and replace every same three letter combination with "2".

->repeat for every unique three letter combination in that column

The dataset above should look like this afterwards:

```
ABC -> 1
DEF -> 2
GHI -> 3
JKL -> 4
ABC -> 1
GHI -> 3
JKL -> 4
JKL -> 4
ABC -> 1
```

---

Is there a way to do this automated search and replace with excel? I can only replace every occurence manually, and would have to do that 300+ times. I could code it but i don't know if it would really save that much time, because I only have to do it once. If there's a library in any language for this specific question it would be great to know though.

Is this possible to do with Microsoft Excel?
If not, is there a library in any language that could solve this problem quickly?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: 1. UNIQUE your list 2. COUNTA the number of rows from this unique list 3.create a column next to the unique list with SEQUENCE with rows defined by the COUNTA result, 1 column, starting from 1 with 1 step 4. use the original list to XLOOKUP to your UNIQUE list returning the matching value from the SEQUENCE column

Comment: i would do a vlookup in another column and then paste over this column as values, not an awesome, but quick.  Set up a table of the unique values (copy and paste column somewhere else and remove duplicates) -> assign the number vales i.e. 1,2,3 etc to each value in the column to the right of the unique values -> do a vlookup in a column to the right of your current one: `vlookup(value, unique values and numbers table (remove to lock this), 2, false)` -> copy and paste vlookup column as values over the original (be sure to be happy with it first and have a back up.

Comment: @Anonymous you beat me to it!  also worth noting that you can check the outcome if you keep a copy of the original table by pivoting both the original and the new and comparing letter combinations of the old column to the numbers of the new (if you do decide to copy the numbers over the letters rather than have a new column)

Comment: Would be great if you try and post your progress and we can support to tweak if necessary. The capital key words are the cell functions. Good luck!

Comment: @InjuredCoding Sorry, mate. “Zwei Dumme, ein Gedanke” comes to my mind (a German idiom). Anyway, yes, I am with you to xlookup to a new column while keeping the original column as well.

Comment: optional: wrapping around =SORT(UNIQUE (…)) will give you the reference numbers according to the alphanumerical order of your 3 letter combos

Comment: @Anonymous, appreciate it being in German as well!  in english its a little different

Comment: Are "first", "second" etc based on occurrence in the list, or on alphabetical order?
In the sample data there is no difference, but that will not always be the case. E.g. ABC, GHI, DEF...

Comment: As implied by other comments, it is easier to think of creating a new column (possibly via several others) with new values (which you can paste to wherever it is needed), rather than actually replace within Excel (although you can Paste Special Values over the original data if you really need that)